# Cowboy websocket Global processing

Tags: erlang, websocket, cowboy

I have a cowboy websocket server. Many clients send message over the websocket. I need to do processing on the message. I can do that in websocket_handle, However as it's realtime I would like to avoid it instead I want to send the message to a Global Process where all the processing can be done.

As Each cowboy has it's own process How to run a process where every user can send message and processing can be done in that process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to clarify, each websocket connection will have its own erlang process in Cowboy, so messages from *different websocket clients* will be processed in *different processes*.

If you need to move the processing from the websocket you can simply start a new handler/server process when your app starts (e.g. when you start Cowboy) that listens for process commands and data. Sample processing code:

```
-module(my_processor).

-export([start/0]).

start() ->
    spawn(fun process_loop/0).

process_loop() ->
    receive
    {process_cmd, Data} ->
        process(Data)
    end,
    process_loop().
```

When you start it, also register the process with a global name. That way we can reference it from the websocket handlers later.

```
Pid=my_processor:start().
register(processor, Pid).
```

Now you can send the data from Cowboy's `websocket_handle/3` function to the handling process:

```
websocket_handle(Data, Req, State) ->
         ...,
         processor ! {process_cmd, Data},
         ...,
         {ok,Req,State}.
```

Note that the `my_processor` process will handle the processing requests from all connections. If you want to have a separate process for each websocket connection you could start `my_processor` in Cowboy's `websocket_init/3` function, store the Pid of the `my_processor`process in the State parameter returned from websocket_init and use that pid instead of the `processor` global name.

Comment: Thanks johlo.. Thats what i have started working on. Actually as requirement is bit complicated I am creating a separate application within my main application.. so I have created a myapp folder inside that i have kept application file and module file. I can compile them using rebar however when i start server i get following error :- {"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{"no such file or directory","rabbit.app"}}},[{websocket,start,0,[{file,"src/websocket.erl"},{line,14}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}} in rebar.config i have set {sub_dirs, ["apps/rabbit"]}.